# Meteor: modals and google maps

Tags: google-maps, meteor, modal-dialog

I am displaying a google map in a modal and I see lots of people have had this issue and there seems to be a fix but so far nothing I've tried has worked.

Basically I am loading googles places search in Template.map.rendered - it seems like something is happening with the DIVs because when I resize the window it re-renders and displays properly.

Now, I have tried all kinds of tricks (hiding / showing various DIVs), calling google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize"); etc.

The map template is being loaded into another template that is a form (with other fields etc).

If someone could point me in a fruitful direction that would be awesome - seems like it should be a simple fix but I'm stumped.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a reproduction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in luck, we just solved our issue regarding this. Assuming the template map is called within a modal:

```
Template.map.rendered = function() {

  Tracker.autorun(function() { 

       Session.set('map_available', true);

       var center = {
          latitude: -1.8445
          longitude: 52.9445
       }; // end var center

       var zoomLevel = 15;       

       if(Session.equals('map_available', true)) {

         GoogleMaps.init({'sensor': true, 'key' : 'OPTIONAL_KEY' },
           function() {

              var mapOptions = {
              zoom: zoomLevel,
              minZoom: 15,
              maxZoom: 20,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
              navigationControlOptions: {
                  style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
              };

              map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions); 
              map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng( center.latitude, center.longitude ));         

           } // end closure param 2 of GoogleMaps init
       }); // end GoogleMaps.init
    } // end Session.equals 'map_available'

  } //end Tracker.autorun

} // end Template.map.rendered




Template.map.destroyed = function() {
   Session.set('map_available', false);
}
```

So the strategy here is to monitor dependency tracking independently and make sure it gets re-added after any DOM reactions. Bonus feature here is that if you include `var center` modification inside `Tracker.autorun` (e.g. `var center = navigator.location`) you will have a map that changes center when you move around (`lat`, `long` has changed).

**Also**, we used the extension `mrt:googlemaps` for the `GoogleMaps` integration. Seems to be the best one to use.

Comment: Ok I'll give it a shot. I actually just used the raw google API code - but this seems simple enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem that stumped me for an hour. My easy fix was to wrap it in a window onload. Try it, you might like it :-)

```
Template.mapsAutoComplete.rendered = function() {
  window.onload = function () {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);
  ...
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I tried this but unfortunately made it not even appear. I'll probably just put this down for now.

Comment: I've tried all of this but the map still doesn't render properly (or I guess since I'm using a map it's already rendered so Template.map.rendered has no effect).

Comment: Here's my fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/cmeethree/sLbskqho/#&togetherjs=FrOzkJLkFz